# Send a Base64 encoded image through HTTP Post Request from Android

Tags: android, image, post, base64, http-post

I am completely lost, I am trying to send a photo via an android app to a php webpage.

Theoritically everything should be right but the destination data is corrupted or something I don't know...

I can get the post data, I tried with a simple string it worked fine but with a heavy file the data seems corrupted.

```
public class EncodingAndSending extends Thread{
    ShareOnMyWebSiteActivity mycontext;
    ContentResolver cr;
    Uri uri;
    public Handler mainHandler,sHandler;

    public EncodingAndSending(ShareOnMyWebSiteActivity myctxt,Handler mainone,Uri URI,ContentResolver crr){
         mycontext=myctxt;
         cr=crr;
         uri=URI;
         mainHandler=mainone;
         this.start();
    }

        return buffer.toString().toUpperCase();    
      }

    public void run(){

        InputStream is=null;
        byte[] data=null;
        try {
            is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
             // Get binary bytes for encode
            data = getFileBytes(is);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String data_string=Base64.encodeToString(data,Base64.URL_SAFE);


        if(data_string!=""){
            SendRequest(data_string);
        }
        else{

        }

    }

public byte[] getFileBytes(InputStream ios) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
            //InputStream ios = null;
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                //ios = new FileInputStream(file);
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ous != null)
                        ous.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // swallow, since not that important
                }
                try {
                    if (ios != null)
                        ios.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // swallow, since not that important
                }
            }
            return ous.toByteArray();
        }


    private void SendRequest(String data_string){

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("xxxxx.php");

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", data_string));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }       
    }

}
```

EDIT:

This works. I can encode and decode and preview the image. I didn't use the getBytes() function I don't know if the problem comes from there.

I'll let you know.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_image);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    FileInputStream in;
    BufferedInputStream buf;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bMap=null;
    try {
        InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);

        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        if (is != null) {
        is.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String data_string=Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    b=null;bMap=null;
    b=Base64.decode(data_string, Base64.DEFAULT);
    bMap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: You can better leave out code that you are not using in your example, such as `byteArrayToHexString`, it only confuses the reader.

Comment: Right, I didn't know if it was relevant or not.

Comment: Can you include the code of method `getFileBytes`? Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: Sure I can, there it is.

Comment: Sorry can not find any obvious bugs... You can debug by printing `data_string` and Base64-decode it and check the result. This way you can see if the problem lies in the reading/encoding or in the http post.

Comment: The thing is that i got the encoded data_string before and after sending and both are corrupted. Maybe I did not get right the image file from the intent extra or maybe because I need to precise a mime type before sending. Dunnow, I tried so many things that I'm quite confused.

Comment: BTW `if (data_string!="")` is not the right way to check if a string is empty. `!=` should never be used to compare two `String`s, use `.equals(...)` instead. Also setting the `ArrayList`'s initial capacity to 2 is not necessary, since it can handle its own capacity pretty well.

Comment: Yes you are totally right, the thing is it was for debugging and I've never seen an error with that checking way. Is it only with special cases or ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is just in the use of `Base64.URL_SAFE` ?

Comment: As for the `!=`, see http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small app that allowed for sending images taken with the phone's camera to a database. Here's how I solved the thing...

```
public void writeCommentForRestaurant(int id, String comment, String author,
        Bitmap image) {

    if (image != null) {
        /* Get the image as string */
        // Normal
        ByteArrayOutputStream full_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, full_stream);
        byte[] full_bytes = full_stream.toByteArray();
        String img_full = Base64.encodeToString(full_bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        // Thumbnail
        ByteArrayOutputStream thumb_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // The getScaledBitmap method only minimizes the Bitmap to a small icon!
        getScaledBitmap(image, 72).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75,
                thumb_stream);
        byte[] thumb_bytes = thumb_stream.toByteArray();
        String img_thumbnail = Base64.encodeToString(thumb_bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // new HTTPWorker(ctx, mHandler, HTTPWorker.WRITE_COMMENT, true).execute(
        // Integer.toString(id), comment, author, img_thumbnail, img_full);
    } else {
        // new HTTPWorker(ctx, mHandler, HTTPWorker.WRITE_COMMENT, true).execute(
        // Integer.toString(id), comment, author, null, null);
    }
}
```

The HTTPWorker is just an asynctask that constructs the HTTPmethod.

```
...
/* Add arguments */
arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idrestaurant", params[0]));
arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", params[1]));
arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("author", params[2]));
if (params.length > 3) {
  arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", params[3]));
  arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bigimage", params[4]));
}
...
```

And then I sent it to the server like this.

```
/**
* Executes a httppost to a server instance with the given POST arguments
* and returns a String response from the server.
*/
private String httppost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> args) {
  /* Create the channel for communicaton */
  InputStream is = null;

  /* Send request to server */
  try {
    /* Create the POST */
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    /* Add the login information "POST" variables in the php */
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(args));

    /* Execute the http POST and get the response */
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    return null;
  }

  /* Read response from server */
  try {
    /* Read the response stream */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

    /* Copy the response to StringBuilder */
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();

    /* Return the response as string */
    return sb.toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well thank you. Actually, the problem was from the server. The base64 is sent to a php script which stores the string into a field... which was a longtext type (mysql). The thing is that corrupts the data, I changed it to blob and it worked fine. Typical isn't it ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

My first topic and a great community is here that's great.

See you later.